# Angular 4 Query Params without Route params

Tags: angular, angular-router

This works (with Route Params = `:id`)

```
{
    path: 'qp/:id?repo=1',
    component: QueryParamsComponent
}

<li><a [routerLink]="['/qp', 5]" [queryParams]="{repo:1}">Query Params</a></li>
```

but without Route Params, it does'nt work,

Is there a way to make below code work?

```
{
    path: 'qp?repo=1',
    component: QueryParamsComponent
}

<li><a [routerLink]="['/qp']" [queryParams]="{repo:1}">Query Params</a></li>
```

Or any other way to achieve this?

This is my QueryParamsComponent

```
repo = ' ';
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.repo = params['repo'];
  });
}
```

**Angular Version: 4.2.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple routes with or without parameter calling  the same component and you don't need to put your queryParams in your routes config:

```
{
 path: 'qp/:id,
 component: QueryParamsComponent
},
{
  path: 'qp',
  component: QueryParamsComponent
}
```

and inside your component :

```
this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.repo= +params['repos'];
 })
```

Comment: My Question is about how to implement Query parameters without route parameters!

Comment: yes i know, there is no need to put your Query parameters in your routes config : "path: 'qp/:id?repo=1" this is wrong, you can use: "/qp" and then you  navigate to this route with query parameters and then read them and do your controle

Comment: I am getting this error Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'qp' 
FOR THIS CODE
`{ path: 'qp?repo=1' }` and `{ path : 'qp/' }` too.

Comment: delete the / , like this {
  path: 'qp',
  component: QueryParamsComponent
} not 'qp/'

Comment: Okay, `path: qp` made my route work but i cannot access query param in my component. I have updated my question with component code receiving query param!

Comment: please use this.router.queryParams not   this.router.params

Comment: Yes, with `this.router.queryParams ` worked. Thank you! Please update your answer!

Comment: i did and don't forget to convert it to number if you need that , using +, because queryParams are returned always as string